# How to load jQuery UI all selected range (not only Min & Max) to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am working on the below code. How can I load the selected range values between Min and Max into an array?

The `selected.push(ui.values);` is giving me the Min and Max of selected which is OK but I also need the values between too.

```js
$( function() {
var selected =[];
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 133,
      max: 146,
      values: [ 133, 146 ],
      stop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        
         $("#dl-sv-input-mmr").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
        selected.push(ui.values);
        console.log(selected)
      },
      
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
selected.push(ui.values[0]);
```

instead of

```
selected.push(ui.values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a loop to push values from lower bound to upper bound:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 133,
    max: 146,
    values: [133, 146],
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var selected = [];
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
      $("#dl-sv-input-mmr").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
      for (var i = ui.values[0]; i <= ui.values[1]; i++) {
        selected.push(i);
      }
      console.log(selected);
    },

  });
  $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
    " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can make an easy function too.

```js
$(function() {
  function fillRange(start, end) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
  }
  var selected = [];
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 133,
    max: 146,
    values: [133, 146],
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
      $("#dl-sv-input-mmr").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
      selected = fillRange(ui.values[0], ui.values[1]);
      console.log(selected)
    },
  });
  $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

This is the same as @SLePort answer just wrapped in a function. It's not indicated why you need these in an array. May consider that if you need, can just test that a value is between the two selected values.